# How do I translate a text in a property using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, ngx-translate-multi-http-loader

Stuck while translating a html text using ngx-translate. I am getting  missing language key error. I have correctly imported the ngx-translation module into this component's module. I am confused on why the translation is working

```
[infoText]="invalidCredentials ? 'Username Incorrect' : ''"
```

I tried translating like this.

```
[infoText]=" (invalidCredentials ? 'login.username-incorrect' : '') | translate"
```

```
[infoText]="invalidCredentials ? ('login.username-incorrect' | translate) : '' "
```

None of this works. Anybody know why?

When I tried like this it works. So can't we translate or ignore empty strings?

```
[infoText]=" (invalidCredentials ? 'login.username-incorrect' : 'login.password-incorrect') | translate"
```

Comment: cant you just define an empty value in lang.json file

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. I will give an example that works for me:

In the `ts` file I have:

```
 constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {...}

 public c1="";
 public c2="";
 public condition =true;

 onchange(ev)
  {   
   this.translate.use('en');
   this.translate.get("<KEY1>").subscribe(x=>this.c1=x);
   this.translate.get("<KEY2>").subscribe(x=>this.c2=x);
  }
```

and in the HTML template I do something like this:

```
 [value]="condition ? c1: c2"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm not able to upvote and mark your answer as correct because of my low reputation. Sorry about that